# ReactiveMongo Extensions: Bulk update using reactive mongo extensions

Tags: mongodb, scala, updates, playframework-2.3, play-reactivemongo

Is there any way to update bulk records. I am trying to update user object using following code:

```
.update($doc("_id" $in (usersIds: _*)), users, GetLastError(), false , true)
```

In above code i am passing, `users` List. in user list i also add new properties and chage existing properties state, but with this statement the records are not update

If i am using following code:

```
.update($doc("_id" $in (usersIds: _*)), $set("inviteStatus" $eq "Invited"), GetLastError(), false , true)
```

The record updated successfully.

Answer (score 0):

From my reading of the [API](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.10.5/api/index.html#reactivemongo.api.collections.GenericCollection) as well as [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500170/upsert-many-records-using-reactivemongo-and-scala?rq=1) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26606925/mongodb-update-a-document-when-exists-already-with-reactivemongo) in this area, I don't think the kind of bulk update you're looking for is possible via the `update` method.

What you *could* do however, is issue a [Raw Command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/update/#dbcmd.update) (credit: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372398/is-there-any-way-to-perform-bulk-updates-on-reactivemongo)), which, if you are patient enough to write the all the `$set` expressions, would definitely work, and be more efficient than a client-side loop doing `save()` operations one-by-one:

**Caution**: compiles, but is untested:

```
import reactivemongo.api.DB
import reactivemongo.bson._
import reactivemongo.core.commands.RawCommand

class BulkUpdater(db:DB) {

  def bulkUpdateUsers(users:List[User]) = {

    def singleUpdate(u:User) = BSONDocument (
      ("q" -> BSONDocument("_id" -> u._id)),
      ("u" -> BSONDocument("$set" -> BSONDocument(
        "firstName" -> u.firstName, 
        "secondName" -> u.secondName) // etc
    )))

  val commandBson = BSONDocument(
    "update" -> "users",
    "updates" -> BSONArray(users.map(singleUpdate)),
    "ordered" -> false,
    "writeConcern" -> BSONDocument( "w" -> "majority", "wtimeout" -> 5000)
  )

  db.command(RawCommand(commandBson))
}
```

Comment: Hello @millhouse, is there a way to run `RawCommand` for `Json` object ?

Comment: It should be possible to define the body of the `RawCommand` as a Play `JsValue` and then convert it to a `BSONDocument` using the [BSONFormats](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/Play-ReactiveMongo/blob/master/src/main/scala/play/modules/reactivemongo/json.scala) from the Play ReactiveMongo library.

Comment: Hey @millhouse, this is not work for me. Following is my code: ` val commandJSON = BSONDocument(
        "udapte" -> "users",
        "updates" -> BSONArray(users.map {userUpdateQueryDocument}),
        "ordered" -> false,
        "writeConcern" -> BSONDocument( "w" -> "majority")
      )`

Comment: When i execute this code ` val doc = userCollection.db.command(RawCommand(commandJSON))
      doc.map { bson => println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>: "+bson) } ` The println statement not run

Comment: my code through following exception : ` reactivemongo.core.commands.DefaultCommandError: BSONCommandError['command faile
d because the 'ok' field is missing or equals 0'] with original doc { `

Comment: My error message is `errmsg: BSONString(no such cmd: udapte)` .

Comment: Check a) that you spelled `update` correctly in the command and b) that you are running Mongo 2.6 or later (`update` first appeared in 2.6)

Comment: hello @ millhouse i am using mongodb `2.6.7` version