# Update with Raw Command in ReactiveMongo 0.12.5

Tags: mongodb, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I am not currently able to run a `Raw Command` in *ReactiveMongo 0.12.5* using the *Play JSON Plugin*. The [documentation (Run a raw command)](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/json/overview.html) is not currently accessible but from a cached page in my browser I can see the following:

```
   import scala.concurrent.{ ExecutionContext, Future }
   import play.api.libs.json.{ JsObject, Json }

   import reactivemongo.play.json._
   import reactivemongo.api.commands.Command

   def rawResult(db: reactivemongo.api.DefaultDB)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[JsObject] = {
     val commandDoc = Json.obj(
       "aggregate" -> "orders", // we aggregate on collection `orders`
       "pipeline" -> List(
         Json.obj("$match" -> Json.obj("status" -> "A")),
         Json.obj(
           "$group" -> Json.obj(
            "_id" -> "$cust_id",
             "total" -> Json.obj("$sum" -> "$amount"))),
         Json.obj("$sort" -> Json.obj("total" -> -1))
       )
     )
     val runner = Command.run(JSONSerializationPack) // run is since deprecated

     runner.apply(db, runner.rawCommand(commandDoc)).one[JsObject] // one is since deprecated
   }
```

However I am not looking to return a `JsObject` (or anything in fact) - I actually want to update all documents in another collection as [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30377600/reactivemongo-extensions-bulk-update-using-reactive-mongo-extensions#answer-30388675) illustrates. My issue is that both methods contain *deprecated functions* and so I have put together a combination to (possibly) work with *JSON Collections* (as mentioned):

```
  def bulkUpdateScoreBA(scoreBAs: List[ScoreBA]) = {

    def singleUpdate(scoreBA: ScoreBA) = Json.obj(
      ("q" -> Json.obj("_id" ->
        Json.obj("$oid" -> scoreBA.idAsString(scoreBA._id))
      )),
      ("u" ->
        Json.obj("$set" ->
          Json.obj("scoreBA" -> scoreBA.scoreBA)
        )
      )
    )

    val commandJson = Json.obj(
      "update" -> "rst",
      "updates" -> Json.arr(scoreBAs.map(singleUpdate)),
      "ordered" -> false,
      "writeConcern" -> Json.obj("w" -> "majority", "wtimeout" -> 5000)
    )

    val runner = Command.CommandWithPackRunner(JSONSerializationPack)

    runner.apply(db, runner.rawCommand(commandJson)) // ?? how to get a Future[Unit] here

  }
```

However I need this to return a `Future[Unit]` so that I can call it from the controller but I cannot find how this is done or even if what I have done so far is the best way. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: As [indicated](https://twitter.com/cchantep/status/965261827667058693), current minor release for 0.x is 0.13, with [0.12 documentation index redirected to](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/).

Comment: I don't see the point of using raw command instead of the [aggregation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.13/documentation/advanced-topics/aggregation.html). Same for [bulk update](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.13/api/reactivemongo/api/collections/GenericCollection.html#update(ordered:Boolean,writeConcern:reactivemongo.api.commands.WriteConcern):GenericCollection.this.UpdateBuilder).

Comment: @cchantep thanks. I read somewhere that using a `raw command` would be the best approach (perfomance-wise) in updating multiple documents. I should explain a little background perhaps - I am trying to ensure that an up-to-date calculated score rating is available in my *team collection* (for normalisation purposes). So I first run an `aggregate` function that creates a new collection (or replaces the old one) with calculated score ratings for each document/team (using the aggregated `out`) - this part works well. _cont

Comment: @cchantep - Then periodically I am looking to update each document/team in the *team collection* with this data. I will take a look at those links (thanks again) to see if they offer any better solutions because ideally this would be done using `aggregation` as you suggest - just got to find if/how. If this somehow changes your recommendation please let me know. Thanks

Comment: I absolutely don't see the point of using RawCommand

Comment: @cchantep I can't see how this would be done with `aggregation`. I can create a new collection or replace an existing one using `out` as mentioned but I cannot see any `aggregation function` which allows me to update particularly fields from another collection

Comment: @cchantep I see from the [documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.13/documentation/advanced-topics/commands.html) that `runCommand` is the best choice when using BSON however I'm using the *Play JSON plugin*. There is a link on that page to show how to do this which navigates me to [running a raw command](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.13/documentation/json/overview.html#run-a-raw-command). I am only going from the documentation and this is why I have been led to believe that this is the way to do it. It's less than clear so if you have a compatible suggestion please post.

Comment: I don't see how you comes to the conclusion that executing raw command is of any benefit from a performance prospective. Documentation never indicates such mention.

Comment: @cchantep I think I got the idea from [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30377600/reactivemongo-extensions-bulk-update-using-reactive-mongo-extensions#answer-30388675). What would you suggest that can work with the *Play JSON plugin/reactivemongo 0.13* (just updated)? You mentioned using the *aggregation framework* but as I say there isn't any functionality to update fields in an existing collection. And I haven't been successful using `update` to pass the `JSON` into each document's target field. So I haven't made any progress. Please elaborate if it is obvious to you

Comment: 1. I "mentioned using the aggregation framework" because it's in your question (where it's not used in the easiest/right way). 2. If you want to check whether MongoDB offer an aggregation "any functionality to update fields in an existing collection", see [online doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/).

Comment: @cchantep 1. If you read the question you will see that the first code (with `aggregation`) is from the documentation. I mentioned in a comment that I am currently creating/replacing existing db collections (with calculated scores) by using aggregation (using the `out` function). 2. I'll say again - I haven't found anything in the `aggregation framework` that updates fields from another collection (including from any of your posted links. I know that you know ReactiveMongo well but this isn't obvious to all of us and I am actively looking for solutions. Feel free to share an example though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Scaladoc for bulk update](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/reactivemongo/reactivemongo_2.12/0.12.7/reactivemongo_2.12-0.12.7-javadoc.jar/!/reactivemongo/api/collections/GenericCollection.html#update(ordered:Boolean,writeConcern:reactivemongo.api.commands.WriteConcern):GenericCollection.this.UpdateBuilder) is available (since 0.12.7), with [example in tests](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo/blob/master/driver/src/test/scala/QueryAndWriteCommandSpec.scala#L115).